# How to access the child lists in cshtml page through model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Unable to access the model List type variables in cshtml page.
Here is my Model Class

```cs
public class MBilling
{
    public List<string> plist { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> qlist { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> splist { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Billing()
{
    if (Session["UserId"] != null)
    {
        MBilling binddata = BillingService.getBindData();
        return View(binddata);
    }
    else
    {
        return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
    }
}
```

Here is the cshtml part

```cshtml
@model IEnumerable<Shop.Models.MBilling>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Billing";
}

<input style="border:none" list="browsers" name="browser">

<datalist id="browsers">
    ///Unable to ACCESS  Model.plist
    @foreach (var item in Model.plist)
    {
    }
</datalist>
```

I'm able to get the model object with required data from service file BUT in cshtml page its showing an error

> CS1061: '`IEnumerable<MBilling>`' does not contain a definition for '`plist`' and no extension method 'plist' accepting a first argument of type '`IEnumerable<MBilling>`' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You rmodel is an IEnumerable, so you need an index. `Model[i].plist` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem:

You're returning the model as an object of type `MBilling` yet using it as `IEnumerable<MBilling>` in the view.

#### Solution:

You do not need `IEnumerable<T>` here, since it's not *enumerable*. So remove it and just do:

```
@model Shop.Models.MBilling
```